# Trials Rising: Poor performance (low FPS) for Laptop with Hybrid Graphic (Intel HD530 / GeForce GTX965M)

Tags: performance, trials-rising

I run Trials Rising on my XMG P406 Laptop.

The configuration:

- Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 965M

I get a framerate of 15 FPS, which is not playable. In "Advanced options" of Trials Rising I choosed the lowest quality setting, and the lowest resolution.

I installed the newest version of the NVIDIA drivers: 419.17 (2019.2.22) 
During installation of the driver I choosed the option to clean old nvidia driver.

I totally fullfill the requirements for the game: https://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=35656&game=Trials%20Rising

Does somebody have an idea what could be wrong, or what else I could try?

Comment: Are you playing on battery power? Laptops always run way slower than their hardware could support when not plugged in. Apparently, that's because the laptop would otherwise drain more power than the battery could safely provide, leading to overheating and the battery (and laptop) burning.

Comment: I play not on battery power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the solution from the Steam Forum: https://steamcommunity.com/app/641080/discussions/0/1840188800785734142/

Worked for me on Windows 10.

Do the following:

1. Right click on desktop and select display settings.
2. Select grahics settings.
3. Under classic app select browse and find the Trials Rising exe file
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Trials Rising\datapack or 
   whatever drive you have Steam installed.
4. Select the exe file and once it is displayed in graphic settings double
   click and select options. Select High performance, and you are good to go.

Important note: That was the first thing what I was doing when I had the problem, but I choosed the file "Launch_Trials_Rising.exe". Make sure you use "datapack/trialsrising.exe", then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in a situation like this, the problem is the game is not running on your dedicated Nvidia GPU, but rather on a secondary integrated GPU which is part of your CPU. Your best bet is to open the Nvidia Control Panel and verify on the "Manage 3D settings" panel that Trials Rising is in fact running using the dedicated Nvidia processor.

However, a further complication is that laptop GPUs are traditionally A LOT weaker than their naming scheme implies. The 965M actually performs somewhere between the desktop variants of the GTX 750 and the GTX 560, depending on the benchmark you use. This means it's only slightly faster than the cards specified in the minimum requirements.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. I posted how I changed it. There is System Setting in Windows 10, I did not need to use the NVIDIA tool for ot.